# How to enable cookies in w3m

Tags: w3m

When I try to login Github, it says 'Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub'. How can I set w3m to enable cookies always?

Does it have any .w3mrc file or something to set it up?

I am using w3m for the default browser in Mutt. This means I am not sure how to add option from Mutt.

Thanks in advance.

I am using w3m on Mavericks+iTerm+zsh+oh=my-zsh.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-cookie` flag:

```
w3m -cookie https://www.github.com
```

This will save the cookie in `~/.w3m/cookie`.

Comment: Since w3m is opened from Mutt, I am not able to add options. Is there any way to set -cookie after opening w3m?

Comment: You should be able to set it in your ~/.w3m/config file, either directly or via w3m's menu, which you can get to by typing `o`. Besides that, though, you can certainly add options to the w3m that's opened from Mutt because Mutt opens w3m only via commands in config files, e.g., muttrc and mailcap, and those are readily changed.